# glsl vertex shader compiles on pc, mac and not on another pc

Tags: glsl, shader, vertex

So, I have a PC with an nvidia geforce gtx 580, a mac with some ATI card and then a notebook with a geforce gtx 680M.

The vertex shader compiles on the 580 and the ATI, but not on the gtx 680M.

The error is quite interesting (not):
**ERROR: 0:18: '': syntax error syntax error**

That line of code is: **int vIdStep = gl_VertexID % 9;**

I have tried to delete all the whitespaces, add extra empty lines, move the line around, ... nothing works.

I use **gl_VertexId** in other shaders that compile without problems. Only this one with the % in it won't compile on the 680M.

What is this?
Anyone else has this experience?
What can I do about it?

EDIT: By the way: this solves the problem, but it's a terrible sollution IMO and I really want a better one:
**int vIdStep = int(mod(float(gl_VertexID), 9));**

Comment: Are your drivers up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what the problem was.
My portable computer has a hybrid video adapter: Intel/Nvidia.
For some reason, even in fullscreen, the driver kept choosing the Intel adapter on my tests.
Therefor... it's a bug in the Intel driver.

You can't use % on glsl on Intel HD Graphics 4000 at this moment. I will now submit the bug to them.